# Reverse printing a linked list using recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, singly-linked-list

I had just tried out a program to reverse print a singular linked list.

Assume that the linked list is ready with 5 elements:
`1->2->3->4->5`

I had written a program to print in reverse order like: `5 4 3 2 1`
But my program just prints as `5 4 3 2`; the `1` is not printing. Why?

```
int Reverse_List(abc_t *pNode) {
    abc_t *pTemp;
    int count = 5;

    if (pNode->pNext != NULL) {
        pNode = pNode->pNext;
        Reverse_List(pNode);
        printf("The node is %d\n", pNode->a);
    }
}
```

Comment: `the 1 is not printing. Why?` `printf("The node is %d\n",pNode->a);` pNode was pNode->pNext

Comment: Suggestion: No need of `int count` and `abc_t *pTemp`

Answer (score 13):

Maybe like this

```
void Reverse_List(abc_t *pNode){
    if(pNode==NULL)
        return;

    Reverse_List(pNode->pNext);
    printf("The node is %d\n", pNode->a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

see how call works

you have list 1->2->3->4->5

now recursion start as

```
pnode = 1;    pnode->next=2; (!NULL)      (print 2)   
  pnode=2;    pnode->next=3; (!NULL)      (print 3)   
    pnode=3;    pnode->next=4 (!NULL)     (print 4)   
       pnode=4;   pnode->next=5 (!NULL)   (print 5)   
          pnode=5;   pnode->next==NULL
```

so here as you can see when you have one it will print two as you advance your pointer

for correct code see @BLUEPIXY's answer